Number of fixed elements of $a\mapsto a^r$ in the group $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}^*$
Suppose $n=pq$, with $p$ and $q$ distinct primes and $r$ is coprime to $\phi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$. Consider the map $f:\mathbb{Z}_n^*\to \mathbb{Z}_n^*$ given by $a\mapsto a^r$, where
Then show that the number of elements that will be fixed by the map $f$ is equal to $\gcd(r − 1, p − 1) \cdot \gcd(r − 1, q − 1)$.
My attempts:
$f(a)=a^r=a$, i.e. $a^{r-1}=1$. We also know that $a^{\phi(n)}=1$. Therefore $a^{\gcd(r-1,\phi(n))}=1$. Hence the order of $a$ divides $\gcd(r-1,\phi(n))$, but $a$ is arbitrary. In $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$, the possible orders are divisors of $p-1$ and $q-1$.
I am unable to proceed further. Any pointers?

Hint: by the (isomorphism of rings underlying the) Chinese remainder theorem, $\Bbb Z_n^\cong\Bbb Z_p^\times\Bbb Z_q^*$.

See also Show that the number of solutions to $x^n\equiv 1 \pmod p$ is $\gcd(n, p-1)$, where $p$ is a prime.

@AnneBauval, thanks for the pointers... This is precisely the same as my question...

Interestingly, the statement here is a little different than the exercise... There is a $+1$ in the RHS product. My exercise is Ex. 3.3 from the book Delfs, Knelbs. Introduction to Cryptography (Springer, 2Ed, 2007)(ISBN 3540492437).. Although, the discussion below explains the "+1", does this mean the exercise in the book is wrong?

Neither your book nor my first link is wrong. This is indeed well explained in the link. There are more solutions in $\Bbb Z_{pq}\cong\Bbb Z_p\times\Bbb Z_p$ than in $\Bbb Z_{pq}^\cong\Bbb Z_p^\times\Bbb Z_p^$. There is one solution more in $\Bbb Z_p$ than in $\Bbb Z_p^$.
